# How to valid each element by onChange in web-ix form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, webix

I have a question relate to valid for each element in form control.

```
webix.ui({
    view:"form", 
    elements:[
        { view:"text", required:true, name:"text1" },
        { view:"text", invalidMessage: "init", name:"text2" },
    ],
    elementsConfig:{
        on:{
           'onChange':function(newv, oldv){
              this.validate();
            }
        }
    },
    rules: {
        text2: function (value) {
            if (!value) {
            $$("text2").define("invalidMessage", "Text2 can not be empty");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

It didn't work with this.validate(). How can we validate for each element with custom valid rule for it.

Answer (score 1):

adds the ID and name to the form.

```
...
id:"form1",
name:"form1",
...
```

the rule

```
rules: {
        "text2":function (value) {
        console.log(value)    
        if (value != "") {
            $$("text2").define("invalidMessage", "Text2 can not be empty");
            return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

See [example](http://webix.com/snippet/e09b8fc7)

Comment: The `name` is critical, `id` can be skipped though.